Inconsistencies between frequentist significance and bootstrapping
I came across the following statement:

Inconsistencies with frequentist significance testing are not unusual and can arise from various factors. Nevertheless, non-parametric bootstrapping is often more reliable when samples are independent and the sample size is sufficiently large.

Is this statement correct? Could anyone provide some references to support this?

Chances are it will help if you tell us where this is from.

My supervisor mentioned this to me, and I wanted to confirm its validity before including it in my manuscript. I have the feeling that such statement is likely something found in textbooks or general statistical references, making it challenging to pinpoint a specific study that supports it directly.

And what did your advisor tell you when you asked them about the validity of their statement?

By "inconsistency" the text may just mean that results are not identical, and obviously if you compute different things, you may end up with different results, so that should not be a surprise. The text may also refer to results being above or below a certain significance threshold, but note that significance thresholds are somewhat arbitrary, and statisticians warn against simplistic binary interpretations of tests for ages. A p-value of 0.039 isn't very different from a p-value of 0.053, and there is no more "inconsistency" in this difference than between p-values of 0.12 and 0.16. The text also says "not unusual", which isn't very useful as a quantifier, because some may think that it means "it happens in half of the cases", but if indeed you run many tests routinely, and it happens in 1 out of 15 cases, say, one could call that "not unusual" as well. So the statement is sufficiently imprecise that it makes little sense to say whether it is "correct" or not.
Note furthermore that the theoretical basis of bootstrap testing uses a frequentist interpretation of probability, and can therefore be called frequentist as well, so the term "frequentist" is used in a way that is questionable to say the least.
Another remark is that statistical model assumptions never hold precisely, which if read superficially may be seen as an argument in favour of nonparametric bootstrap as model assumptions of classical non-bootstrap tests will be violated in reality, however samples in reality aren't truly independent either, so the independence assumption in the statement will also be violated. Note further that with large samples and independence, many non-bootstrap methods work beyond their nominal model assumptions because of the Central Limit Theorem, and there is even some theory that says that bootstrap works well in the same situations in which non-bootstrap statistics may also work well with large samples (see Enno Mammen, When does bootstrap work? https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-2950-6).
Otherwise how the characteristics of a certain bootstrap test relate to the characteristics of a classical (non-bootstrap) test that is supposed to test the same null hypothesis surely depends on the exact situation we're talking about, how exactly the tests are set up, and how in fact the data were generated.
I'm certainly not against nonparametric bootstrap (I use it myself occasionally), but when to prefer it to alternatives is a more subtle issue than the statement suggests (if in fact the statement suggests anything precise anyway, as it says "often" but not how often).
I think if a student of mine wrote this in a project thesis, rather than saying whether it is correct or not, I would ask the student to give me references and to define unclear terms more precisely, and I'd expect that the student will have a hard time finding them and will therefore remove the statement, not because it's wrong but because it's rather empty, and I prefer people to know more precisely what they're saying or otherwise better not say it (if they didn't remove it, it wouldn't be a big bad thing though; students get away with worse, even at PhD level).

Thank you for your answer! I agree that the statement, on its own, lacks precision. The background is that in a simple regression, the p-value was 0.13, whereas the bootstrap analysis indicated a 95% confidence interval of [-0.51, -0.016].
I plan to keep the first part of the statement. It implicitly suggests that bootstrap is a frequentist method, and sounds reasonable (though a bit empty).

I should say "Inconsistencies between frequentist significance testings are not unusual and can arise from various factors."

@Emma Depending on your application, a regression parameter of -0.016 may be so small that it doesn't merit interpretation as something meaningful anyway. Furthermore, in order to assess this, one would need to know how many bootstrap samples you used, for knowing how much variation there might be in the bootstrap result given the data, on top of some other potentially useful knowledge about your data.

@Emma I very much hope that you didn't use the bootstrap only after you saw that the classical test is not significant, to have another shot at finding significance. If this were the case, the bootstrap test would be invalid, as deciding to run it based on something that you saw on the same data violates the assumptions of most statistical tests (all those that don't take this explicitly into account).

The accuracy of the bootstrap, with respect to ordinary inference, depends on the agreement between the bootstrap distribution and the sampling distribution.  SImple simulations often show these disagree, and it doesn’t matter if you use a nonparametric vs. a parametric bootstrap.  I think of the bootstrap as a quick and dirty substitute for Bayesian modeling which does require prior distributions but provides exact inference.

The sample size for this particular case is 43, and I have a total of 60 similar cases. For all cases, I ran both simple regression and bootstrapping simultaneously, as I am concerned that the assumptions of linear regression may not fully hold for my datasets (since bootstrapping is relatively less sensitive to violations of normality and heteroscedasticity?). In most of the cases, the results from both methods align in terms of significance.

Indeed @FrankHarrell it sometimes seems like that’s what Efron intended (Bayesian part) especially if you read Computer Age Statistical Inference (great book IMO)
